# Button onClick not redirecting

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

SO..i have this project that is totally backwards, but basically i have to give a working form that adds a quantity of some item_ID and then redirects to the cart page of a framework i use.

Of course rather than me just skin my framework, and customize its functionality for him. This guy has some hacked up php pages that he "wrote himself" that he insists on hard coding forms into.

anyways, i have a form that submits to my cart.php in the action

```
<form name="orderform" method="post"     action="http://s429036015.onlinehome.us/cart.php" id="orderform">
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="140" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="" />
    Qty <input type="text" id="product_avail" name="amount" />      
   <button class="button main-button list-button add-to-cart-button" type="submit" title="" onClick="location.href='cart.php'">
    <span class="button-right"><span class="button-left">Add to cart</span></span>
  </button>       
</form>
```

The above form submits properly, with the quantity entered, session stores the data and the items are in the cart just fine....however, that `onclick` event on the `<button>` doesn't work!

I've even tried this

```
<button class="button main-button list-button add-to-cart-button" type="submit" title="" onClick="GotoPage(); return:true;">
```

with this script ahead of the form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function GotoPage() {
    window.location = "http://s429036015.onlinehome.us/cart.php";
  }
</script>
```

anyone have any ideas? driving me nuts...

Comment: Why you want add onClick event to button? If button inside form it sends data by default! Try to disable javascript and try my solution

Comment: How are a form submit action and a JavaScript redirect both supposed to work simultaneously?

Comment: By the way is s429036015.onlinehome.us the domain where form is?

Comment: It works fine here, pasted the code 1:1 into a blank html and a click jumps to the shoppingcart. However, there is a _NO_COOKIE_WARNING=2&ti=dbb97ded1a9acdc1d769695b882b261d_ in the header. What browser do you use? maybe IE or another browser does not like the "illegal" onClick (with capital C)?

Comment: seems that the whole issue is the cookie. would be nice if it just submitted the data to the cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, after you process data from form, try this:

```
header('location: http://s429036015.onlinehome.us/cart.php');
```

Comment: i was trying to limit hacking the cart framework, but this seems to be my only option.